# Condensing a data frame in R to one row

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I have a list of data frames, and the data frames in the list look something like this where the columns `x_`, `y_`, and `t_` all have the same values in each role and the only thing differnt are the `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` values:

| x_ | y | t_ | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | NA | NA |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | NA | 9 | NA |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | NA | NA | 20 |

Here is the code for an example of the data frame above:

```
df <- data.frame(x_ = c(1,1,1),
                 y_ = c(1,1,1),
                 t_ = c(1,1,1),
                 var1 = c(5, NA, NA),
                 var2 = c(NA, 9, NA),
                 var3 = c(NA, NA, 20))
```

I would like to get the data frames to look something like this, where I can condense the data into a single row:

| x_ | y | t_ | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 20 |

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential option is to fill the NAs then remove duplicate lines, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vctrs)

df <- data.frame(x_ = c(1,1,1),
                 y_ = c(1,1,1),
                 t_ = c(1,1,1),
                 var1 = c(5, NA, NA),
                 var2 = c(NA, 9, NA),
                 var3 = c(NA, NA, 20))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~vec_fill_missing(.x, direction = "downup")))
df2
#>   x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
#> 1  1  1  1    5    9   20
#> 2  1  1  1    5    9   20
#> 3  1  1  1    5    9   20

df2 %>%
  distinct()
#>   x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
#> 1  1  1  1    5    9   20
```

---

If you have NAs for every line, this will have NA in the final distinct row:

```r
df3 <- data.frame(x_ = c(1,1,1),
                 y_ = c(1,1,1),
                 t_ = c(1,1,1),
                 var1 = c(5, NA, NA),
                 var2 = c(NA, 9, NA),
                 var3 = c(NA, NA, NA))

df4 <- df3 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~vec_fill_missing(.x, direction = "downup")))
df4
#>   x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
#> 1  1  1  1    5    9   NA
#> 2  1  1  1    5    9   NA
#> 3  1  1  1    5    9   NA

df4 %>%
  distinct()
#>   x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
#> 1  1  1  1    5    9   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Possibly. Does this method remove NA's? In my actual data, some of the values are actually NAs (e.g., the 20 under var3 could be an NA). I would still want to keep that NA value for example.

Comment: It will still keep NAs as NAs, i.e. if there are no real values in var3 you will end up with NA for var3

Comment: Perfect, thanky you so much!

Answer (score 3):

An easy way with base:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, median,na.rm=TRUE))

  x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
1  1  1  1    5    9   20
```

With all NA's in one column:

```
df <- data.frame(x_ = c(1,1,1),
                 y_ = c(1,1,1),
                 t_ = c(1,1,1),
                 var1 = c(5, NA, NA),
                 var2 = c(NA, 9, NA),
                 var3 = c(NA, NA, NA))

data.frame(lapply(df, median, na.rm=TRUE))

  x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
1  1  1  1    5    9   NA
```

There's a potentially even easier way with `aggregate`..

```
aggregate(  . ~ x_ , df , median , na.rm=TRUE , na.action=NULL )

  x_ y_ t_ var1 var2 var3
1  1  1  1    5    9   20
```

Comment: This gives the correct answer with the example data, but it doesn't keep NAs when a var has only NAs, per John's comment below (it returns Inf)

Comment: i just changed `min` to `median` to fix that :-)

Comment: Nice! Median is a good fix (+1)

Comment: it also works with non-numerics which surprised me, so long as there's only one non-missing element in the column.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation, assuming the values you want to keep only appear once per x/y/z grouping.

```
df %>%
  group_by(x_, y_, t_) %>%
  summarize(across(var1:var3, ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```